# Handling Nested Directories In Flask

Tags: python, flask, directory, subdirectory

I am trying to build a folder viewer app with Flask. But i stuck at handling nested subfolders .
I don't know how many directories in my folder

```
app = Flask(__name__)
folder_scheme = get_folder("Workspace")

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html",folder_scheme= folder_scheme)

@app.route("/<string:folder>")
def subfolder_handler(folder):
    for subscheme in folder_scheme["subfolders"]:
        if subscheme["name"] == folder:
            return render_template("index.html",folder_scheme=subscheme)
    return "Nothing here!"
```

This is my code.I can only view first subfolders . For instance if my subfolders have subfolder i can't reach or make link like /Subfolder1/Subfolder2/Subfolder3 to that folder.

```
Workspace/
└── Subfolder1
    └── Subfolder2
        └── Subfolder3
           ├── file1
           ├── file2
           └── file3
```

Is there a automated way to handle or link to view that sub folders.

```
@app.route("/<string:folder>")
def subfolder_handler(folder):
    for subscheme in folder_scheme["subfolders"]:
        if subscheme["name"] == folder:
            return render_template("index.html",folder_scheme=subscheme)
    return "Nothing here!"
```

That function makes me reach to first subfolders . But i am looking for the function for all subfolders.
Shortly I am trying to do some replicate of this simple server (with Flask).

```
import http.server
import socketserver

PORT = 8080
Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
    print("serving at port", PORT)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: That is not the problem. The thing that i want to do is simple TCP server that i can view and download the files in the main directory. But in Flask I can't show each subdirectory because i can't write route function for each subdirectory. For instance if i had 300 subdirectory, how can i show the files in that subdirectory. Shortly i am trying make server like that ```import http.server
import socketserver
PORT = 8080
Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
   print("serving at port", PORT)
    httpd.serve_forever() 
```

Comment: I dont think there is an automated or an existing way to delve into the inner subfolders of the directory you pass in. You would have to build a custom function using the `os` module to achieve this. At least this is how i see it.

Comment: I sent a code piece. That is the thing that i am trying to do in Flask. I will try to add to question.

Comment: ok, will have a look

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`os.walk()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) to recursively iterate through a directory and all its subdirectories using the following.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for folder in dirs:
       print(folder)
```

You can thus put this in a function which when passed in a `path` will return the folders. You can then recursively call to obtain the folders as you mentioned, e.g. `/Subfolder1/Subfolder2/Subfolder3`